# How to union 2 tables with multiple fields by LINQ?

Tags: linq, union

I have 2 tables:

Table 1

name    counter

A        1 

B        2 

C        3

Table 2 

name counter 

A       2 

B       2 

C       3

How to get the following result?

name counter

 A       1

 A       2 

 B       2

 C       3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data comes from a relational database, and the ORM layer is Linq2Sql or Entity Framework, then extend the data objects (the "rows" in the table) through **partial class** syntax to override the **Equals** method (override it with the required semantics, like the two fields should be identical) and use the Enumerable.**Union** extension method.

Or use the Union extension method with an other overload, which takes an **IEqualityComparer** object. In that object you can implement the comparison. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358407.aspx)

If the two tables are so different, that different classes are generated for them, then you should wrap them in a 3rd class (adapter design pattern) to be able to use a collection of them together and use a method mentioned above.

Comment: Is there any simple way like: var result = (from a in table1 select new {a.name, a.counter}).Union(from b in table2 select new {b.name, b.counter}); ?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to do it, without having to ovverride the Equals method IF you are using Linq to Entities. The comparision will be done on the SQL server, so all fields will have to be equal in order to "match" and remove duplicates. In Linq to objects you have to override the equals method, or provide the IEqualityComparer.

Comment: But I am using LINQ to SQL, is it possible?

Comment: Actually if you use anonymous types like you mentioned in your comment, that should work out of the box, because Equals is automatically overridden by the compiler for you. If you name the properties identically and the order of properties is the same in the two anonymous types, then they are the same type and Union should filter the duplicate rows. [Example on MSDN](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Set-Operators-374f34fe#union2)